# how to find intersection of django models?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have three models universities,user type and user.University model contain list of all university and user type contain two type of user type faculty and student and user model contains all the users.

Now, what I want to achieve is get all the users which belongs the university intersections of user type.
Suppose I selected abc university and user type faculty then how can i get all the user from that abc university with faculty type.

May my models help you to understand better:-

university model:-

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

# WE ARE AT MODELS/UNIVERSITIES

class Universities(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(db_column="id", max_length=11, help_text="")
    name = models.CharField(db_column="name", max_length=255, help_text="")
    abbreviation = models.CharField(db_column="abbreviation", max_length=255, help_text="")
    address = models.CharField(db_column="address", max_length=255, help_text="")
    status = models.BooleanField(db_column="status", default=False, help_text="")
    createdAt = models.DateTimeField(db_column='createdAt', auto_now=True, help_text="")  
    modifiedAt = models.DateTimeField(db_column='modifiedAt', auto_now=True, help_text="")  
    updatedBy = models.ForeignKey(User,db_column="updatedBy",help_text="Logged in user updated by ......")

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        get_latest_by = 'createdAt'
        db_table = 'universities'
```

my user type model:-

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models

# WE ARE AT MODELS/MASTER USERS TYPES

class MasterUserTypes(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(db_column="id", max_length=11, help_text="")
    userType = models.CharField(db_column='userType', max_length=255, help_text="")
    description = models.CharField(db_column='desciption', max_length=255, help_text="")
    status = models.BooleanField(db_column="status", default=False, help_text="")
    createdAt = models.DateTimeField(db_column='createdAt', auto_now=True, help_text="")  
    modifiedAt = models.DateTimeField(db_column='modifiedAt', auto_now=True, help_text="")  
    updatedBy = models.ForeignKey(User, db_column='updatedBy',
                                  help_text="Logged in user updated by ......")

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'master_user_types'
```

and users models :-

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from cms.models.masterUserTypes import MasterUserTypes
from cms.models.universities import Universities
from cms.models.departments import MasterDepartments



# WE ARE AT MODELS/APPUSERS

requestChoice = (
    ('male', 'male'),
    ('female', 'female'),
    )


class Users(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(db_column="id", max_length=11, help_text="")
    userTypeId = models.ForeignKey(MasterUserTypes, db_column="userTypeId")
    universityId = models.ForeignKey(Universities, db_column="universityId")  
    departmentId = models.ForeignKey(MasterDepartments , db_column="departmentId",help_text="")  
    name = models.CharField(db_column="name",max_length=255,help_text="")
    username = models.CharField(db_column="username",unique=True, max_length=255,help_text="")
    email = models.CharField(db_column="email",unique=True, max_length=255,help_text="")
    password = models.CharField(db_column="password",max_length=255,help_text="")
    bio = models.TextField(db_column="bio",max_length=500,help_text="")
    gender = models.CharField(db_column="gender",max_length=6, choices=requestChoice,help_text="")
    mobileNo = models.CharField(db_column='mobileNo', max_length=16,help_text="")  
    dob = models.DateField(db_column="dob",help_text="")
    major = models.CharField(db_column="major",max_length=255,help_text="")
    graduationYear = models.IntegerField(db_column='graduationYear',max_length=11,help_text="")  
    canAddNews = models.BooleanField(db_column='canAddNews',default=False,help_text="")  
    receivePrivateMsgNotification = models.BooleanField(db_column='receivePrivateMsgNotification',default=True ,help_text="")  
    receivePrivateMsg = models.BooleanField(db_column='receivePrivateMsg',default=True ,help_text="")
    receiveCommentNotification = models.BooleanField(db_column='receiveCommentNotification',default=True ,help_text="")  
    receiveLikeNotification = models.BooleanField(db_column='receiveLikeNotification',default=True ,help_text="")  
    receiveFavoriteFollowNotification = models.BooleanField(db_column='receiveFavoriteFollowNotification',default=True ,help_text="")  
    receiveNewPostNotification = models.BooleanField(db_column='receiveNewPostNotification',default=True ,help_text="")  
    allowInPopularList = models.BooleanField(db_column='allowInPopularList',default=True ,help_text="")  
    xmppResponse = models.TextField(db_column='xmppResponse',help_text="")  
    xmppDatetime = models.DateTimeField(db_column='xmppDatetime', help_text="")  
    status = models.BooleanField(db_column="status", default=False, help_text="")
    createdAt = models.DateTimeField(db_column='createdAt', auto_now=True, help_text="")  
    modifiedAt = models.DateTimeField(db_column='modifiedAt', auto_now=True, help_text="")  
    updatedBy = models.ForeignKey(User,db_column="updatedBy",help_text="Logged in user updated by ......")
    lastPasswordReset = models.DateTimeField(db_column='lastPasswordReset',help_text="")
    authorities = models.CharField(db_column="departmentId",max_length=255,help_text="")

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'users'
```

so how can i find the intersection....pardon me if you find any mistakes.
Thansk in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

will the user enter the staff type and university name?

then what you can do is like

```
User.objects.filter(usertype_id=inputted_id, university_id=inputted_id)
```

Comment: when user tell me the staff tye and university name then i want all the users that belongs to the university and specific staff type

Comment: yes the above query will help you with what you are trying to achieve.
check and let me know if the result is not desirable to you.

cheers

Comment: that worked i was using multiple value of university and usertype so i used usertype_id__in.thanks

Comment: great. pleasure that helped you :)